# scrlayer-scrpage: Can't increase pagehead font size beyond \normalsize (but decreasing works!)

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fontsize, scrlayer-scrpage

I'm trying to increase the font size of the page head, and it doesn't increase beyond `\normalsize`. Here's my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[
fontsize=24pt, pdftex, a4paper,
DIV=50, BCOR=0pt, twoside=off,
headlines=2,
footlines=2,
headinclude=on,
footinclude=on,
mpinclude=off,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\addtokomafont{pagehead}{
%   \small
%   \normalsize
%   \large
    \Large
}

\defpagestyle{myStyle}{
    (0pt,0pt)
    {}{}{My header}
    (\textwidth, 3\arrayrulewidth)
}{
    (\textwidth, 3\arrayrulewidth)
    {}{}{My footer}
    (0pt,0pt)
}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{myStyle}
    Content
\end{document}
```

By toggling the comments for the different sizes, you can see that decreasing the size below `\normalsize` has an effect on the output, but increasing it does not.

I also tried

```
\fontsize{40pt}{48pt}\selectfont
```

but it also does not have any effect.

What am I missing? How can I increase the font size of the page head?

Comment: add `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` before \documentclass.

Comment: That indeed fixes it, thank you! Can you explain it? And if you write it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Though it's not like you need the rep :D

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, fonts were only available in certain fixed sizes. You could not just scale the fonts to an arbitrary size; if a size wasn't provided, you couldn't use it. This is also the case for LaTeX's default font *Computer Modern*, which is why your MWE isn't working the way you want it to.

The usual recommendation is to just use a more modern font that allows arbitrary scaling. As an equivalent to Computer Modern there is Latin Modern which you can use by simply saying

```latex
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

in your preamble.

If you instead want to stick to Computer Modern as closely as possible (there are some small differences), you can use [`fix-cm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fix-cm) instead, which you have to load by saying

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
```

*before* `\documentclass`. For more details, see its documentation.